# Laplace Equation in a Cylinder with Some Uncommon Boundary Conditions

Tags: functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

While I was working on some theorems in PDEs, I encountered the following **axisymmetric** boundary value problem

$$\matrix{
   {{\nabla ^2}H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{in}}} \hfill & \Omega  \hfill  \cr 
   {\partial_r H+a \partial_z H+bH=0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {r = R} \hfill  \cr 
   {H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {z =  - \ell } \hfill  \cr 
   {H = 0} \hfill & {{\rm{on}}} \hfill & {z = \ell } \hfill  \cr 
 } $$
such that $\nabla^2=\partial_{r}^{2}+\frac 1r \partial_r+\partial_{z}^{2}$ is the axisymmetric Laplace operator and $H:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$ is an infinitely differentiable scalar field $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^3)$. Also, $a$ and $b$ are some real constants. The domain $\Omega$ is a cylinder defined as

$$\Omega  = \left\{ {(r,\phi ,z)|0 \le r \lt R,0 \lt \phi  < 2\pi , - \ell  \lt z \lt \ell } \right\}$$

where $(r,\phi,z)$ is the usual cylindrical coordinates.

What can we say about the uniqueness of $H$?

Comment: If neither the differential operator in the interior nor the boundary conditions depend on $\varphi,$ isn't this a two-dimensional problem?

Comment: @Justpassingby: No, it is a 3D problem which has a symmetry with respect to $z$ axis. :)

Comment: What is the sign of $b$? If $b \ge 0$, the only solution is $H = 0$. Let $X = \partial \Omega \cap \{ (r,\phi,z) : r = R \}$,
$$\begin{align}\int_\Omega |\nabla H|^2 
&= \int_\Omega ( \nabla\cdot(H\nabla H) - H\nabla^2 H)
= \int_\Omega \nabla\cdot(H\nabla H)
= \int_{\partial\Omega} H\nabla H
= \int_{X} H\partial_rH\\
&= \int_{X} \left( -\frac{a}{2} \partial_z H^2  - b H^2\right)
= -\frac{a}{2}\int_{\partial X} H^2   - b \int_X H^2
= -b \int_X H^2
\end{align}
$$

Comment: @achillehui: I don't get your conclusion? Can you kindly write an answer with proper details? I did the same thing up to the equation $$\int_{X}-\frac{a}{2}\partial_zH^2-bH^2$$ before asking the question. But cannot understand what you did after this equation and how an integral over $\partial X$ appeared! Also, how did you conclude that $H$ should be only zero if $b \ge 0$? I cannot see any clues for that!

Comment: 1) $\int_X \partial_z H^2 = \int_{\partial X} H^2$ and $z = \pm \ell$ on $\partial X \implies H = 0$ there. 2) If $b \ge 0$, then $\int_\Omega |\nabla H|^2 + b \int_X H^2$ is a sum of two non-negative terms, it can only be zero when both terms are zero. The first one implies $H$ is constant inside $\Omega$ and since we know $H = 0$ when $z = \pm \ell$, $H = 0$ over whole $\Omega$.

Comment: What theorem do you use for the equality $\int_X \partial_z H^2 = \int_{\partial X} H^2$? :)

Comment: $\int_X \partial_z H^2 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_{-\ell}^{\ell} \partial_z H^2 dz d\phi = \int_0^{2\pi} [ H^2 ]_{z=-\ell}^\ell d\phi$.

Comment: @achillehui: Many thanks for the useful guides. :) I wrote an answer below based on your guides. :)

Comment: The real problem is what happens when $b < 0$.
If $a = 0$ and for some $(m,n) \in \mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}_{+}$, following condition is satisfied.

$$k_n I'_m(k_n R) + b I_m(k_n R) = 0\quad\text{ where }\quad k_n = \frac{n\pi}{2\ell} $$

Your PDE has non-trivial solution of the form

$$I_m(k_n r)  \sin(k_n(z+\ell)) \times \begin{cases} A,& m = 0\\
B \cos(m\phi) + C\sin(m\phi) & \text{ otherwise } \end{cases}
$$
where $I_m(x)$ are [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I.CE.B1.2C_K.CE.B1) and $A, B, C$ are constants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just rewriting the discussions, above in the comments, with  **achille hui** as an answer.

First, we note the general identity

$$\psi \nabla^2 \phi = \nabla \cdot (\psi \nabla \phi) - \nabla \phi \cdot \nabla \psi$$

and by choosing $\psi=\phi=H$ we get

$$H \nabla^2 H = \nabla \cdot (H \nabla H) -  |\nabla H|^2 \tag{2}$$

Let $X$ be defined as the lateral surface of the cylinder

$$X=\left\{ {(r,\varphi ,z)|r=R,0 \lt \varphi  < 2\pi , - \ell  \lt z \lt \ell } \right\}$$

Next, integrate $(2)$ over $\Omega$, use the divergence theorem and the boundary conditions on $X$ to get

$$\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (H \nabla H) dV - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= \int_{\Omega} H \nabla^2 H\\
\int_{\Omega} \nabla \cdot (H \nabla H) dV - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV  &= 0\\
\int_{\partial \Omega} H \nabla H \cdot {\bf{n}} dS - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0\\
\int_{X} H \nabla H \cdot {\bf{n}} dS - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0\\
\int_{X} H \partial_{r}H dS - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0\\
-a\int_{X} H \partial_{z}H dS - b \int_{X} H^2 dS - \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}a\int_{X} \partial_{z}H^2 dS + b \int_{X} H^2 dS + \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}aR \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{-\ell}^{\ell} \partial_{z}H^2 dzd\phi + b \int_{X} H^2 dS + \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0 \\
\frac{1}{2}aR \int_{0}^{2\pi} [H^2(R,\phi,\ell)-H^2(R,\phi,-\ell)] d\phi + b \int_{X} H^2 dS + \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0 \\
b \int_{X} H^2 dS + \int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &= 0
\end{align}$$

Next, **if we assume** that $b \gt 0$ we can conclude

$$\begin{align}
\int_{X} H^2 dS &= 0 \\
\int_{\Omega} |\nabla H|^2 dV &=0
\end{align}$$

and hence

$$\begin{align}
H^2 &=0 & \text{on} & \quad X \\
|\nabla H|^2 &=0 & \text{in} & \quad \Omega
\end{align}$$

which finally leads to

$$H=0$$